# How to uninstall Tomcat from MAC OS X

Tags: macos, uninstall, tomcat

I have tomcat installed in my MAC 10.10.5 
 It was running fine on first installation. 
After that I have changed some configuration and now I am not able to see localhost:8080

I am using

> ./bin/startup.sh

to start server.

> Using CATALINA_BASE:   /Library/Tomcat
>   Using CATALINA_HOME:   /Library/Tomcat
>   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /Library/Tomcat/temp
>   Using JRE_HOME:        /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home
>   Using CLASSPATH:       /Library/Tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/Library/Tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   Tomcat started.

It shows Tomcat started but localhost doesn't work. 
Connection port and other configurations are same

> ```
> <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
>            connectionTimeout="20000"
>            redirectPort="8443" />
> ```

```
<tomcat-users>
<!--
<role rolename="role1"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/>
<user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
<user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
-->
</tomcat-users>
```

Now I want to install fresh build, for that I want to remove Tomcat completely from mac. Anyone know that how to remove it?

Comment: Instead of uninstalling/reinstalling why don't you **fix** the existing install?

Comment: I tried to resolve the problem, I will update the post once I got any error.